# database copy with same structure having primary key issues

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a scenario,

I have two databases **DB1** and **DB2**. Both database have **same structure**.

DB1 contains a table "table1" with **AUTO INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY** 1,2,3,4,5 and DB2 also contains "table1" with primary key 1,2,3,4,5. when I insert data from DB2 to DB1, the data from DB2 will become 6,7,8,9,10. But I need 1,2,3,4,5 for data from DB2 and 6,7,8,9,10 as DB1 data..

Can I use this query?

```
mysqldump -n -t -u userB --password=*** db2 | mysql -u userA --password=*** db1
```

is it possible?

Comment: Db1 contains `1,2,3,4,5` and also you want to insert `1,2,3,4,5` from db2?

Comment: yes.Both table contains 1,2,3,4,5 as primary key values. That is my issue here. Also the primary key is auto increment.

Comment: How you want to store in db1 where primary key will not allow duplicate value

Comment: The value of autoincrement primary key is supposed to be a meaningless number. It shouldn't matter what set of records gets the 1,2,3 and which one gets 6,7,8.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight But that is the primary key. Also I need this structure, bec, I need to put the new data in the first order than the existing data in DB1.

Comment: @Sadikhasan So only I need to change the values ...

Comment: The only important thing about a primary key is uniqueness. If your database is designed correctly, you should be able to replace a sequential 1,2,3 with three random unique numbers, say, 34, 9963, and 1000066927, and the system would not change its behavior.

Comment: @Sadikhasan so is it possible for me without changing the database table structure???

Comment: If I had two containers, #1 with wheat and #2 with rice and wanted to put the wheat into #2 *under* the rice, I would likely use a third container.

Comment: @AndriyM haha I got the concept... I just digged, if there exists any technique is there or not... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @MaxId INT
SELECT @MaxId = MAX(Id) FROM Db1

SET IDENTITY_INSERT db1 ON
INSERT INTO Db1(Id, Column1, Column2, ...)
SELECT @MaxId+ ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY Id),
    Column1,
    Column2,
    ...
FROM db2
SET IDENTITY_INSERT db1 OFF
```

Try this..

Answer (score 1):

**You may use one of these two scenorio**

First:

- Copy db1.table1 data in temp table
- Truncate db1.table1
- Copy data from db2.table to db1.table1
- Copy data from temp table to db1.table

Second:

- Copy db1.table1 data to db2.table1
- Truncate db1.table1
- Copy data from db2.table to db1.table1

**Use can use this mysql command for copying data:**

insert into dbDestination.tblDestination (field1, field2, ...)
select ...
from dbSource.tblSource

Comment: This will not work if there are foreign key constraints involved.

Comment: Agreed. We can Disable foreign key constraints temporary using SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

Comment: @felix, Need not to separate create db, we need to create separate temp table

Comment: @khanz this database has many tables... So I have t0 create separate dataabae... :)

Answer (score -1):

First Truncate the "table1" in DB1 before inserting data from DB2 to DB1
  because It may have set "Auto increment id=6"

Comment: If I truncate the table, I will all data from my DB1. This is not allowed. I need the data from DB1 and DB2. But the order of primary key values in DB2 must be in first than DB1.